# How do I reverse geocode a dictionary of address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, geocoding

This is the code I have so far for reverse geocoding my address:

```
-(void)getJobs:(NSData *)responseData{


    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    NSArray *array1 = [json valueForKey:@"activities"];
    NSArray *array2 = [array1 valueForKey:@"activity_where"];
    NSArray *array3 = [array1 valueForKey:@"activity_city"];

    NSMutableArray * addresses = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 0; i < [array2 count]; i++)
    {
        NSString * geocodeAddresses = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                                        [array2 objectAtIndex:i],
                                        [array3 objectAtIndex:i]];
        [addresses addObject:geocodeAddresses];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [addressDictionary setObject:addresses forKey:@"array"];

    NSLog(@"%@",addressDictionary);
```

Whenever I log this out I get the following:

```
   array =     (
        "some address",
        "some address",
        "some address",
      );
}

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:[addressDictionary valueForKey@"array"] completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {

            // Process the placemark.
            NSString *latDest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
            NSString *lngDest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate =
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latDest doubleValue],
                                       [lngDest doubleValue]);
            UserAnnotation *annotation = [[UserAnnotation alloc] init];
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Now I'm trying to reverse geocode all of these address from my dictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Well the code only reverse geocodes the single address in the dictionary, and I need it to plot all 3 of the addresses that I logged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues above:

1) You are trying to reverse geocode an address string, not a dictionary of information about the address. You should use

```
    geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:
```

2) Once you get the address strings into an array, you need to loop through each one and call the above method on them. There is also no need to add them to an address dictionary. Take the mutable "addresses" array and do the following

```
   for (NSString *address in addresses)
      {
         CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
         [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
         {

          // Process the placemark.
             NSString *latDest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
             NSString *lngDest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude];

             CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate =
             CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latDest doubleValue],
                                   [lngDest doubleValue]);
             UserAnnotation *annotation = [[UserAnnotation alloc] init];
             [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
          }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I see where I went wrong here, but I keep ending up with extraneous closing braces, and expected "[" in my errors now.

Comment: Those are just minor syntax errors that should be easy to track down. Did you run the code above?

Comment: I'm trying to run the code above but there is just something that's just not letting me do it. I'm only adding two more braces and so there really shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What line is the error being raised at? and what is the error description?

Comment: Well the method that follows this one has an error in red that says "use of undeclared identifier.." and there are ones within the method that say extraneous brace, and expected identifier.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing in the second loop with NSDictionary *title. However, syntax wise erase the first bracket in [geocoder geocodeAddressString and then add one more } to the end

Comment: Yeah, that totally fixed it! Thanks a ton!